# number of states with n pairs

Tags: probability, combinations

I'm a biochemist but randomly stumbled on a probability problem that would be useful to solve but I'm finding a bit tricky.

Suppose you have $n$ particles that can form pairs. How many discrete states exist in which those $n$ particles are arranged to form $m$ pairs?

I have a recursive definition right now, from the idea that as you add particles, you can make a pair with it and $n-1$ others:

$S(n,m) = (n-1)  S(n-2, m-1) + S(n-1, m)$

$S(n,m) = 0$ where $n<2m$, $S(n,0)=1$ and $S(n,1)=$ $ _nC_2$

Can someone help me find an explicit formula (or tell me that none exists)?

Comment: Does the order of the pairs matters?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the order within the pair and the order of pairs don't matter.

Given $n> 2m$, for the first pair of the particles, there are ${n \choose 2 }$ ways to choose the particle.

For the second pair, there are ${n-2 \choose 2 }$ ways to choose.

$\vdots$

And for the last pair, there are ${n-(2m-2) \choose 2 }$ ways to choose the particle.

The total will be calculated as: $$\frac{{n \choose 2}{n-2 \choose 2}\dots{n-(2m-2) \choose 2}}{m!}=\frac{n!}{(n-2m)!m!2^{m}}$$

---

We can verify this with a small example. Let's say that there are 4 distinguishable particles and we want to see how many ways we can form $1$ pair, i.e. $m=1$. Possible ways are $12,13,14,23,24,34$, total of 6 possible ways. $\frac{4!}{2!1!2^1}=6$.

Now, let's say we want 2 pairs. Possible ways are $(12,34), (13,24)(14,23)$, total of 3 possible ways. $\frac{4!}{0!2!2^2}=3$.

Comment: Does this approach take into account the overcounting from choosing the same $m$ pairs in a different order?

Comment: No my answer is wrong. let me edit my response.

Comment: I have edited my answer. This is how far I have got! Please let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: This makes sense and passes all of my tests using the recursive algorithm. Thanks!